# Finding missing entries between two Dictionaries

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Suppose that I have two dictionaries as such:

```
Dictionary<int, int> a = new Dictionary<int, int>(), b = new Dictionary<int, int>();
a.Add(1, 1);
a.Add(2, 2);
a.Add(3, 3);
b.Add(1, 1);
b.Add(2, 2);
```

What's the best way to extract the difference between them and returning it in a `Dictionary<int, int>` type ?

Comment: you can view this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851155/finding-difference-between-two-dictionaries

Comment: @cFrozenDeath do you want to get in a third dictionary the entries that are not on both dictionaries?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath I don't know how to answer this question... if I'm having a problem, I can lay out my logic and what I've tried. If I have a general question, what am I supposed to say that "I've tried" in that case? Should I really post my own solution (I do have one)? Wouldn't that affect future answers? For reference, I actually am asking because I don't know.

Comment: @AbdellahOUMGHAR I did search this question before posting and was unable to find that question that you linked. That question does more or less what I was trying to do here.

Comment: @LightToTheEnd no problem it happens, but essentially you have solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var dict3 = dict1.Except(dict2).Concat(dict2.Except(dict1);
```

Or :

If you've already checked that the keys are the same, you can just use:

```
var dict3 = dict2.Where(entry => dict1[entry.Key] != entry.Value)
                 .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

To explain, this will:

- Iterate over the key/value pairs in dict2
- For each entry, look up the value in dict1 and filter out any entries wherethe two values are the same
- Form a dictionary from the remaining entries (i.e. the ones where the dict1 value is different) by taking the key and value from each pair just as they appear in dict2.

Note that this avoids relying on the equality of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` - it *might* be okay to rely on that, but personally I find this clearer. (It will also work when you're using a custom equality comparer for the dictionary keys - although you'd need to pass that to `ToDictionary`, too.)

Comment: "Or using LINQ:" Both versions are LINQ.