# How to determine if two List<FileInfo> contain the same elements using MSTest?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to figure out how to determine when two `List<FileInfo>` are different. Why is MSTest telling me these two are different with `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent` or `SequenceEqual`?

The test fails with: `CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The expected collection contains 1 occurrence(s) of <C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\WPF\PenIMC.dll>. The actual collection contains 0 occurrence(s).`

```
    string basePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"),
                                   @"Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\WPF");

    var fiList1 = new List<FileInfo> { new FileInfo(Path.Combine(basePath, "PenIMC.dll")) };
    var fiList2 = new List<FileInfo> { new FileInfo(Path.Combine(basePath, "PenIMC.dll"))};

    CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(fiList1, fiList2); //why is this failing?
    //And this one too...
    Assert.IsTrue(fiList1.SequenceEqual(fiList2));
```

I can get this to work with simple types such as `int` similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007495/difference-between-two-listfileinfo), however not with my `List<FileInfo>`. If you cannot determine this just by looking at my code above, maybe offer a clever way to investigate this - such as serializing the objects to XML and I can diff them. I'm guessing that I'm missing something however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this has to do with reference equality. If you store the `new FileInfo` in the same variable, then this works. So, you have to use a complex type that overrides the `Equals` method

Comment: So simply create my own comparer type to override eqauls like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007495/difference-between-two-listfileinfo

Comment: Seems that way if it is not something you can override.

Comment: I guess I would not have expected this given the description of CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent..."Elements are equal if their values are equal, not if they refer to the same object."